# How to emulate my Android Phone in System

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can i emulate my Android Phone?. i.e How can i operate my Android Phone through System, like change the settings, browse the applications. (My phone is Xperia X10 mini pro). Is it possible.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your Phone settings->applications->development->USB Debugging . Check that and plug your phone in. If you have the SDK installed correctly you should able able to see your phone. If you use Eclipse this is easy. Otherwise you could use ddms from the cl

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK includes an Emulator. Have a look at [this site](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).
I believe it only emulates vanilla Android, so you wont get the same GUI as on you Xperia phone.